# URL Rewrite Syntax issues R:0, R:1, R:2

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, url, redirect

so I have a rewrite in place that is not operating as I would have expected.

I have a site URL that is registered but is not connected to an active site and instead directs to a sub-page of the active site.

EG: somesite1.com -> somesite2.place.org/subpage/somesite1area

The issue is that I have been needing to add a catch for a sub-link:

EG: somesite1.com/subpage2 -> somesite2.place.org/subpage/somesite1area/subpage2

Here is the original rewrite:

```
<rule name="somepage1 redirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.|)somepage1\.(org|com|net)$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://somesite2.place.org/subpage/somesite1area" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Here is the rewrite change that I was testing (But didn't work)

I added a {R:1} to the end of the redirect URL to capture and apend the path.

```
<rule name="somepage1 redirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.|)somepage1\.(org|com|net)$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://somesite2.place.org/subpage/somesite1area/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

to the best of my knowledge, this should work. what am I missing here?

Comment: instead of R:1 use R:0. It will work fine.

Comment: Strange. I must have had a publishing error. 

Because I had tried {R:0} but for some reason, it decided to work this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Rajesh G!

Using {R:0} fixed this for me.